# LaTeX (Overleaf) says that equation references (eqref) are undefined, but they're apparently ok. What Am I missing?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, natbib, revtex

LaTeX (Overleaf) says that references eq1 and eq:2 are undefined, but they're apparently ok.

What Am I missing here? MWE is provided. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,book,showpacs,%
  nofootinbib,aps,superscriptaddress,%
  eqsecnum,prd,notitlepage,showkeys,10pt]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} 
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Test}
\affiliation{test@test.com}

\begin{abstract}
In this work...
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

As stated in \eqref{eq1}:

\begin{equation}
a+b \label{eq1}
\end{equation}

Equation \eqref{eq:2} states that

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:2}
b + c = x
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :)

Comment: You get many errors due to `biblatex` that cannot be used with `revtex4-1`

Comment: The red number next to the green Recompile is the number of errors.  When there's an error, TeX will start making guesses about the output, and you shouldn't believe the output too much.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are throwing too much in ... This reduced code works:

```
%\documentclass[twocolumn,book,showpacs,   nofootinbib,aps,superscriptaddress, eqsecnum,prd,notitlepage,showkeys,10pt]{revtex4-1}
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{dirtytalk}
%\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} 
%\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{}

\begin{document}

\title{Test}
\author{Test}
%\affiliation{test@test.com}

\begin{abstract}
In this work...
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

As stated in \eqref{eq1}:

\begin{equation}
a+b \label{eq1}
\end{equation}

Equation \eqref{eq:2} states that

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:2}
b + c = x
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

**Result**:
[image: Result]

Looks like there is some unwanted interaction. To locate the problems, I suggest repeating, what I did: strategic "deletion", i.e. commenting-out, of packages.

Comment: Nice! This works, but I need to find a workaround, because I've been using Bibtex as default! Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean for %\addbibresource{references.bib} ? Well, it couldn't compile in my place, obviously ;-)